# How do I use DOM element's attribute value as a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got a number of dynamic values assigned to variables from outside the form. And I need to pass them to form. Now, I could do each field individually like this.

this would be the form

```
<form>
     <input type="text" class="inputfield widthfield" id="widthval" />
     <input type="text" class="inputfield fontsizefield" id="fontsize" />
</form>
```

And this would be jquery

```
widthval = '300px'
fontsize = '15px'
$(".widthfield").val(widthval);
$(".fontsizefield").val(fontsize);
```

and so on. But there is a ton of these fields, and this doesn't look right. So, I was wondering if there is any way to use field id to match field and variable.
Something like this perhaps (the logic).

```
$(".inputfield").each(function(){
     matchattr = $(this).attr("id");
     $(this).val(matchattr);
});
```

In this case, it uses the actual value of an attribute. How do I turn that value into variable that has the dynamic value assigned to it?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question.  `matchattr` is a variable that contains the dynamic value.

Comment: matchattr contains id of the input field. In this case, for .widthfield that would be 'widthval', and i'm trying to add var widthval (in this case '300px') value to .widthfield Trying to find efficient way to assign variable values to fields without listing them individually.

Comment: this is very simple, just loop trough elements inside the form var form = document.querySelectorAll('form'); and check if the id's of the elements match whatever you want to compared with.

Comment: @Jose CC My kung fu is not quite there yet.

Comment: I understand @Samij but searching is key for learning.

Comment: If I understand you well i think you could do `$(this).val(eval(matchattr));` but I do not recommend to use it like this.

Answer (score -1):

Given that your variables match the ids of the inputs, you could put your values in an object, loop over the keys, and set them when they match.

```js
var data = {
  widthval: '300px',
  fontsize: '15px'
};

var $inputfields = $('.inputfield');

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key){
  $inputfields.filter('#'+ key).val(data[key]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
     <input type="text" class="inputfield widthfield" id="widthval" />
     <input type="text" class="inputfield fontsizefield" id="fontsize" />
</form>
```